# 'erase' part of image created with GD

Tags: php, gd

I am working with PHP 5.3/5.4 and GD.

I have used the following code to create an image canvas:

```
$col = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$bg = ImageColorAllocate($col, 42, 208, 77);
```

After I do this, I do some drawing. This all works just fine.

However, once I am finished, I need to 'erase' a certain percentage of the top of the image.

Once I have determined the area to be 'erased', how can I erase so that only the background is left? (or erase the background too would be fine)